# Mocha test freezes after failing assert

Tags: mocha.js

So I am using mocha to test my simple express app.
Tests are working perfectly until the first failure. After it fails tests freezes in some assert (promise) loop.

If sumInPromise function is not a promise, then it works as should. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Code:

```
describe("Dummy test", () => {

  before((done: Done) => {
    app ? done() : initStart()
      .then(() => {
        while (app == null) {
          //empty
        }
        
        done();
      })
      .catch((err) => done(err));
  });

  after((done: Done) => {
    app ? done() : closeServer()
      .then(() => done())
      .catch((err) => done(err));
  });

  const sumInPromise = (a: number, b: number) => {
    return Promise.resolve(a + b);
  };

  it("OK, dummyPromise", async (done: Done) => {
    const sum = await sumInPromise(2, 2);

    assert.equal(sum, 5);

    done();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used old way of writing mocha tests... I can't fully explain why and how, but promises should be returned. This is my current code that works:

```
  it("OK, dummyPromise", () => {
    return sumInPromise(2, 2).then(sum => assert.equal(sum, 5));
  });
```